# Is it possible to check if a contract has an event?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, events

I'm iterating through different blocks with the intent of finding every block in which an nft is deployed. I plan on doing this by checking for openzepplines ERC721 event. How do I check if a contract has an event? Thanks!

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

class TransactionChecker {
    web3;
    account;

    constructor(account) {
        //this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:3232'));
        this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
        this.account = account.toLowerCase();
    }

    async checkBlock() {
        let latestBlock = await this.web3.eth.getBlock('10861675');
        let latestNumber = latestBlock.number;
        let contractNumber = 0;
        for (let i = 10861673; i <= latestNumber; i++) {
            let block = await this.web3.eth.getBlock(i);
            let number = block.number;
            if (block != null && block.transactions != null) {
                for (let txHash of block.transactions) {
                    let tx = await this.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
                    if (tx != null) {
                        let contract = tx.contractAddress;
                        if (contract != null) {
                            console.log("Contract found on block: " + number);
                            console.log(contract);
                            console.log(contractNumber);
                            contractNumber++;
                            if (contract.events != null) {
                                console.log(contract.allEvents);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the track I have taken to try and achieve my goal.

```
if (contract.events != null) {
  console.log(contract.allEvents);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes you can !

I've recently found a way to find out whether or not a contract has a certain method (can't find the link, sorry), it is almost the same for events. (I believe there isn't an `events` array in the transaction receipt). I believe that you can't actually get a list of the events of a certain contract, the events are hidden in the bytecode of the contract, you need to check for a specific event. Here is the function:

```js
async function contractHasEvent(contractAddress, eventSignature) {
    // client is the Web3 instance
    const contractCode = await client.eth.getCode(contractAddress);
    const eventSignature = client.eth.abi.encodeEventSignature(eventSignature);
    const hasEvent = code.indexOf(eventSignature.slice(2, eventSignature.length)) > 0;
    return hasEvent;
}
```

An event signature is of this form `EventName(argumentTypeOne,argumentTypeTwo,...)`. Note that there is no space between argument types. For example, I believe you have this transfer event in ERC-20 or ERC-721 tokens: `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`.

For ERC-721, you would need to check if the contract has these events:

- `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`
- `Approval(address,address,uint256)`
- `ApprovalForAll(address,address,bool)`

If you want to check if a contract has a method, you can create a similar function and just replace `client.eth.abi.encodeEventSignature` by `w3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature`

**Things you might want to check**:

- [EIP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165): Standard Interface Detection because it is widely used in ERC-721 (be careful, all the contracts implementing ERC-721 methods might not implement ERC-165 `supportsInterface` method)
- For your specific use, in addition to checking events, you should check if the methods you want are implemented ([ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721#specifications), look at the methods)

Good luck for your project !

*Disclaimer: I do not fluently speak english (I try my best) nor I am a smart contract expert, just a random crypto enthusiast*

Comment: A couple of things that should be considered if using this approach: 1/ it doesn't work for proxied contracts (you will be reading the proxy bytecode, not the real contract), 2/ false positives for function signatures: bytecode might have 4 bytes that look like an event but it is unrelated code (This might work for event signatures because having 32 random bytes match a signature is highly unlikely), 3/ false negatives: using assembly it is "easy" to hide events by dividing the 4 bytes in two parts.

Comment: Ohh didn't know that much about it, it never worked wrongly with me, It seems to be indeed very unlikely, thanks for the comment ! What do you propose to improve the function ?

Comment: The solution works in many cases, just be aware of the few shortcomings. I don't know what's the proper way to improve it, perhaps simulating the contract execution.